# How to run remote ssh command with multiple commands using quotes?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, remote

I have tried many combinations, but none of those have worked, and now my ideas have run out.

So my intension is to get time from scheduled at-job, and make another AT-job half an hour before it. And run that command in for loop to many computers.

I have gone this far, but this makes the AT-job in the source linux, not in the destination:

```
ssh linuxserver atq | awk '{print ($3), $2}' | { read time; date -d "$time -30 min" "+%H:%M %F" ; } | { read time2; echo "yum upgrade -y" | at "$time2" ; }
```

Then I'm sure that the for-loop makes the quoting more difficult, but I can't test it before I can make this previous command work. I would then use for-loop like this:

```
for loop in $(cat /tmp/names)
do 
ssh $loop atq | awk '{print ($3), $2}' | { read time; date -d "$time -30 min" "+%H:%M %F" ; } | { read time2; echo "yum upgrade -y" | at "$time2" ; } 
done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Such arrangements are probably best done with a script in the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `bash` you can use the `printf '%q\n' "$command"` pattern to get a valid command. First, make a valid *local* command like this:

```
atq | awk '{print ($3), $2}' | { read time; date -d "$time -30 min" "+%H:%M %F" ; } | { read time2; echo "yum upgrade -y" | at "$time2" ; }
```

Now [put it into a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) so that when echoed you get the exact same result. The easiest way to do this is to use single quotes wherever possible, and double quotes where necessary (*only* to wrap single quotes):

```
$ cat command.sh
atq | awk '{print ($3), $2}' | { read time; date -d "$time -30 min" "+%H:%M %F" ; } | { read time2; echo "yum upgrade -y" | at "$time2" ; }
$ command='atq | awk '"'"'{print ($3), $2}'"'"' | { read time; date -d "$time -30 min" "+%H:%M %F" ; } | { read time2; echo "yum upgrade -y" | at "$time2" ; }'
```

You can verify that these are the same with `diff`:

```
$ diff command.sh <(echo "$command")
$ echo $?
0
```

Now print that so that you can put it in an `ssh` command:

```
printf '%q\n' "$command"
atq\ \|\ awk\ \'\{print\ \(\$3\)\,\ \$2\}\'\ \|\ \{\ read\ time\;\ date\ -d\ \"\$time\ -30\ min\"\ \"+%H:%M\ %F\"\ \;\ \}\ \|\ \{\ read\ time2\;\ echo\ \"yum\ upgrade\ -y\"\ \|\ at\ \"\$time2\"\ \;\ \}
```

Ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

With your command only the `atq` command is run in the remote machine, you have to pass only one long command line enclosed in single quotes:

```
ssh linuxserver '  command1 'command2' command3  '
```

But there are single quotes inside your command line so you can escape them like this:

```
ssh linuxserver $'  command1 \'command2\' command3  '
```

So the result would be:

```
ssh linuxserver $' atq | awk \'{print ($3), $2}\' | { read time; date -d "$time -30 min" "+%H:%M %F" ; } | { read time2; echo "yum upgrade -y" | at "$time2" ; } '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! :) But I don't understand the meaning of the $ sign in front of the single quotes?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to be too clever with `ssh hostname command arg1 arg2 ... argN` syntax. Create a shell script on the remote host and let it do the work, rather than burning your coworkers eyes' out with all the quoting. I.e.:

```
$ ssh linuxserver /usr/local/bin/my_atq.sh
```

Comment: Yes I know that it would be much easier to do that way, but I don't want to copy scripts to all servers. It works now, and I have learned something new.